# Null pointer exception while building and running bottomnavigation activity

Tags: java, android, navigation

I've a `button` in a fragment, on click of that `button` leads me to a new activity which has `bottomnavigation`.
**Button:**

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/driveBtn"
        android:layout_below="@id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
        android:text="Book a Cab"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

**Code to redirect to new activity:**

```
case R.id.driveBtn:
                Intent intent3 = new Intent(getContext(), DriveActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent3);  
                break;
```

**DriveActivity:**

```
public class DriveActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drive);
        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);
    }

}
```

**activity_drive:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    tools:context=".view.ui._activity.DriveActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

When I try running that app, I get this error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
> at androidx.navigation.ui.ActionBarOnDestinationChangedListener.setTitle(ActionBarOnDestinationChangedListener.java:48)
> at androidx.navigation.ui.AbstractAppBarOnDestinationChangedListener.onDestinationChanged(AbstractAppBarOnDestinationChangedListener.java:103)
> From where is that `ActionBar` being called?
> at androidx.navigation.NavController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(NavController.java:233)
> at androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(NavigationUI.java:227)
> at com.dell.mycampus.view.ui._activity.DriveActivity.onCreate(DriveActivity.java:27)

Comment: Are you using a `NoActionBar` based theme for your activity?

Comment: No... This is my code in `AndroidManifest`, `<activity android:name=".view.ui._activity.DriveActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_drive"/>`

Comment: What is the `android:theme` at your `application` level? Does that theme use `NoActionBar`?

Comment: It uses `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` whose parent is `Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert`.

Comment: So just to be clear, your theme for your entire app and every activity within it is one suitable for an `AlertDialog`? Is that intentional on your part?

Comment: I know that it doesn't sound so good, but this was developed by another developer, I took over from him, you know the pains of poorly documented code, right? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert` is a theme appropriate for a `Dialog`. Specifically, an [`AlertDialog`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AlertDialog). Dialogs do not have an action bar, so it is expected that an Activity using that theme will not have an action bar, resulting in `getSupportActionBar()` always returning null.

When you say `setupActionBarWithNavController()` you are saying you want to set up your action bar with your NavController. Since have no action bar, it is expected that every call to `setTitle`, `setDisplayHomeAsUp()` and other [`ActionBar`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/ActionBar) API fail with a `NullPointerException`.

If you want a theme that includes an action bar by default, you should use a `Theme.AppCompat.Light` theme for your activity.

Comment: Okay... I'll add a note in my calendar to talk with the developer who added `Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert` as parent style. Thank you.